# Java HDFS client receiving "is already the current lease holder" error when appending

Tags: hdfs

I am trying to append to an HDFS file. When I do, I get the error:

```
2017-06-14 14:51:10,068 INFO  [net.psgglobal.hdfs.videovault.videostorage.VideoDatedFile] (VideoDatedCacheWriter) Error appending image bytes 2568018 index bytes 360: Failed to APPEND_FILE /PSG/VideoVault/VideoStorage/VICADS-0/108/20170614.img for DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_330993248_1145 on 192.168.3.214 because DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_330993248_1145 is already the current lease holder.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:3108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2904)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:3211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFile(FSNamesystem.java:3180)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.append(NameNodeRpcServer.java:766)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.append(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:640)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2351)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2347)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2345)
```

Since I am the lease holder, what is the problem? How can I release the lease?
David

Answer (score 0):

You can release the lease on a file as follows:

```
hdfs debug recoverLease -path <path-of-the-file> [-retries <retry-times>]
```